# long distance cat5 run

Tags: ethernet, cat5

I need to run a cat5 cable 400'. I know this is just a little over the 325' that the 'standard' says cat5 can do, and will probably work. But we'd like to make sure this isn't a weak link in the system. Can I just put a simple switch in the middle as a signal boost or do I need a specialized 'repeater'? If so, what product am I looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple switch should do the job. So would a hub.
From the point of view of signal amplifying, all work the same. It all comes down to the price.

Answer (score 1):

A simple switch will work. The limit is per segment, and a switch generates different segmetns on every side.

Answer (score 1):

75 feet isn't just "a little" over the limit, it's 25% over the limit. That being said, a switch in the middle should be all you need.

Comment: Plus the standard restricts how close to other cords the e5 cable can be placed. Which will add the overhead.